# How do I read an RMS file from a Nokia S40 device?

Tags: java, java-me, rms, series-40

I have an RMS file generated on an S40 Nokia phone - is there any way of reading this on a PC? I'm trying to debug an issue on the phone, which seems to be related to the contents of the RMS, and extracting it on a desktop machine seems like a good way of dealing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Java ME Project on the Computer System which can read the RMS generated by your Phone. To Transfer your Phone's RMS you need a USB Cable which can connects directly  in to computer system. Make sure you create your new Java ME Project with the same name , as it is .Jar file in the Phone.

Comment: When you say Project, do you mean in the sense of the Wireless Toolkit SDK (or NetBeans or Eclipse)? And once the project is created, how do you read the RMS?